# Using Google Sheets or Python to cluster a directed graph (or matrix)

Tags: python, algorithm, google-sheets

Hello all and thank you for your time.

I have a group of about 100 people. Each user has liked 3 of the other 99 users. These people need to be divided in about 4 groups of roughly equal size. They need to be grouped together so that the groups consist mostly of people who like each other, or at least as much as possible.

To make the problem a bit more challenging, I need to take into account gender and nationality but that could be done on a second level.

I have tried to create a matrix (directed graph) in Google Sheets but I am now stuck when it comes to clustering them. I am happy to use Python once I have identified the algorithms needed. Any suggestions please?

Thank you!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39954745/2095090